# Conjectures on fractions where each digit appears once in numerator and denominator

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, gm.general-mathematics, permutations

This is a highly redacted version of a question that was asked before. Please see [Criteria of considering relevance of the question to the domain of research topics](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1792/criteria-of-considering-relevance-of-the-question-to-the-domain-of-research-topi) for details.

Some numerical experimentation (which could be considered recreational mathematics) has led to some curious observations which I don't properly understand but which might have number-theoretic import. I am hoping experts here can shed some light. If this is not considered appropriate for MathOverflow, then I apologize, and I ask for advice on a more suitable place to ask.

Among recreational enthusiasts, it has often been noted that the rational number

$$\frac{9876543210}{1234567890}$$

is very close to being an integer (the exact value is $8.0000000729$). What seems to be less well-known is that there are a number of such fractions, in which each digit appears exactly once in the numerator and denominator, with the same value as above, provided that we allow $0$ to be a leading digit:

$$\frac{7901234568}{0987654312}\;\; \frac{6913580247}{0864197523}\;\; \frac{4938271605}{0617283945}\;\; \frac{3950617284}{0493827156}\;\; \frac{1975308642}{0246913578}\;\; \frac{0987654321}{0123456789}$$

Each of these has the same value $8.0000000729$, or $\frac{109739369}{13717421}$ as a rational number in reduced form.

In more formal terms, there are thus $7$ pairs of permutations $(\phi, \psi)$ on the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$ such that the base 10 expansions

$$[\phi, \psi] := \frac{\sum_{i=0}^9 \phi(i) \cdot 10^i}{\sum_{i=0}^9 \psi(i) \cdot 10^i}$$

all yield the same value $\frac{a}{b}$.

Thus, let us define two permutation pairs $(\phi, \psi)$ to be *equivalent* if they yield the same rational value $[\phi, \psi]$ displayed above. Some equivalence classes are very large: the one where $[\phi, \psi] = 1$ has $10! = 3628800$ pairs, and the one where $[\phi, \psi] = 10$, given by $w0/0w$ where $w$ is a string with nine nonzero digits, has $9! = 362880$ pairs. Let us discard those possibilities as uninteresting, and consider just those pairs where $1 < [\phi, \psi] < 10$. Then some extensive computer experimentation, courtesy of R. Cano and described in detail in a Mathematics Stackexchange thread [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/283117/43208), suggests that $7$ is the size of the largest equivalence class for the remaining pairs, and this size is attained just for the value $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{109739369}{13717421}$ or its reciprocal.

My questions have to do with what happens in other bases besides base 10.

> **Question 1:** For other bases $r$, consider permutations $\phi$ on the set $\{0, 1, \ldots, r-1\}$, and again define an equivalence relation on pairs of permutations $(\phi, \psi)$ where two such are equivalent if they yield the same rational value 
>   $$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{r-1} \phi(i)\cdot r^i}{\sum_{i=0}^{r-1} \psi(i)\cdot r^i}.$$ 
>   As above, let us restrict attention to pairs where $1 < [\phi, \psi] < r$. What is the size of the largest equivalence class? Calculations for the cases $r = 2, 3, \ldots, 10$ seem to yield, respectively, the sizes $2,2,3,3,5,3,7,5,7$. This looks suspiciously like one of the OEIS sequences [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C2%2C3%2C3%2C5%2C3%2C7%2C5%2C7&language=english&go=Search), all having to do with Euler's totient function.
>
> **Question 2:** Which rational value $\frac{a}{b}$ represents this largest equivalence class? Putting $n = r-1$, my conjecture is that
>   $$\frac{(n - 1) (n+1)^{n+1} + 1}{(n+1)^{n+1}-n^2-n-1}$$ 
>   yields the maximum number, although there could be more than one such fraction. (Note that this is just a closed form expression for the base-$r$ expression $\frac{n\; n-1\; \ldots\; 1}{1\; 2\; \ldots\; n}$, analogous to $\frac{987654321}{123456789}$.)

There are other questions that could be asked; more can be found at the Mathematics StackExchange link given above. But this would be a good start for me.

PS - this version of the question is kindly written by Todd Trimble with additional input from Gerry Myerson. I am very much thankful to Gerry and especially to Todd for their time and help in trying to improve the quality of my question!

Comment: As I noted at another discussion of this question, if $w$ is any of the 362,880 9-digit numbers using all digits except zero, then $w0/0w=10$, and 362,880 is considerably bigger than 7. OP explained that what's wanted is ratios strictly between 1 and the base, but that detail seems to have been omitted in the current incarnation of the question.

Comment: This is a very preliminary comment -- I'm doing various calculations -- but I suppose it hasn't escaped your notice that the subject seems very closely related to base-$r$ representations of $1/(r-1)^2$?